# Como criar uma single page no Wordpress para um post-type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Criei um Post-Type específico em functions.php:

```
// Meus posts types
function meus_posts_type() {
    // Testemunhos
    register_post_type('testemunhos',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(

                'name'  => __('Testemunhos'),
                'singular_name'     => __('Testemunhos')
            ),
            'public'        => true, 
            'has_archive'   => true, 
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-format-chat',
            'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),

        )    
        );

        register_post_type('consultorias',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(

                'name'  => __('Consultorias'),
                'singular_name'     => __('Consultorias')
            ),
            'public'        => true, 
            'has_archive'   => true, 
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-clipboard',
            'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),

        )    
        );

        register_post_type('treinamentos',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(

                'name'  => __('Treinamentos'),
                'singular_name'     => __('Treinamentos')
            ),
            'public'        => true, 
            'has_archive'   => true, 
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
            'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),

        )    
        );

        register_post_type('clientes',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(

                'name'  => __('Clientes'),
                'singular_name'     => __('Clientes')
            ),
            'public'        => true, 
            'has_archive'   => true, 
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
            'supports'      => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),

        )    
        );
}

add_action( 'init', 'meus_posts_type' );
```

Ok.

Fiz uma página "page-treinamentos.php" com:

```
<?php 

get_header(); 

/*
    Template name: Treinamentos
*/

?>


<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<section class="features18 popup-btn-cards cid-rlWkB2eQKv" id="features18-y">




    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="mbr-section-title pb-3 align-center mbr-fonts-style display-2"><strong>WORKSHOPS E TREINAMENTOS</strong></h2>
        <h3 class="mbr-section-subtitle display-5 align-center mbr-fonts-style mbr-light"><strong>GOVERNOS | EMPRESAS | ONGs (IN-COMPANY
)</strong><div>Workshops e treinamentos especializados em gestão integrada de resíduos sólidos
</div><div><br></div></h3>

<?php
            if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
            yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>' );
            }
        ?>

<?php query_posts( 'post_type=treinamentos' ); ?>

       <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
.......
```

Porém, quando clico no link que quero, o single.php não mostra o post do post-type, mostra o 404.php.

Como posso ler o post do post-type? Tenho que criar um single-nomeDoSingle.php? Se sim, como seria esta estrutura?

Meu single.php está desta forma:

```
<?php get_header();?>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="container">
<?php
            if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
            yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>' );
            }
        ?>
     <center>
    <h1><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
    </center>   
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-9">


        <?php
            if (have_posts()): the_post();
                    the_post_thumbnail('medium_large', array('class' => 'img-fluid'));
                    the_content();
            endif;
        ?>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-1') ) {
                dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1');
            } ?>    
        </div>
        <!--<div class="col-md-3">
            <?php //get_sidebar('personalizado') ?>
        </div>-->
    </div>
</div>

<?php //get_footer('personalizado'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fala parceiro! tudo beleza?

Você pode fazer single específicos para post types dessa maneira abaixo:

**single-testemunhos.php

single-consultorias.php

single-treinamentos.php

single-clientes.php**

Depois você pode seguir com mesma estrutura que é na single.php

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    // Include the page content template.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

ou seja, a hierarquia funciona dessa forma:

**single-MEU_POST_TYPE**

E assim, funciona também da mesma forma, para a página de arquivos, veja:

**archive-testemunhos.php

archive-consultorias.php

archive-treinamentos.php

archive-clientes.php**

Espero que te ajude!

Valeu.

Answer (score 1):

Sim. A estrutura dele é identica a um `single.php`.

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    // Include the page content template.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                endwhile;
            ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

[Esse link ajuda.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50372/create-a-single-page-for-a-custom-post-type/50377)

Comment: Editei com o meu 'Single.php'. Da forma que você apresentou está meu 'Page.php' para listar, preciso mostrar o conteúdo do que já está listado em um 'post_type' .... @daviaragao

Comment: Não entendi o que você disse.